# Как редактировать сообщение с картинкой и текстом в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram, бот, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть телеграм бот который каждый раз нажимая на кнопку редактирует сообщение кнопки и изображение (по идеи)
Как редактировать и текст и изображение?
`Bot.edit_message_text`
Не сообщение с картинкой а
`Bot.edit_message_text`
При редактировании не редактирует текст
Выдает ошибку